# Deal with Excel file on server

Tags: java

I am new in Java, but I wrote a code to extract terms form large datasets and save the results on MS-Excel file.

When I run the code on my laptop, its work fine without errors and give me the needed results and save them into the Excel file.

I put the file on a server, but when I run the code on it, it gives me errors regarding the Excel file. Here is an example of errors:

```
package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
                                  ^
NXParser.java:19: error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
                                  ^
NXParser.java:20: error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
                                  ^
NXParser.java:21: error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
                                  ^
NXParser.java:22: error: package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

and so on...

I do not know what is the problem.

Another thing, I use this command when dealing with files (either input or output) to get the path:

```
File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\output.xlsx");
```

should I keep the path like this when using the server?

Many thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

The package does not exist... The library you're trying to use is not available on your server.

You have several options:

1. Compile on your development machine and upload the compiled program to the server.
2. Add the library to your server manually.
3. Use something with dependency resolution, like Maven or Gradle, to build on the server.

Comment: I tried to compile the code on my laptop, but it give me the same errors